# Detecting URL in using spaCy

Tags: python, spacy

```py
import spacy
text = "Schedule time with me Google<https://nam02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=http://calendly.com/helloKitty>"
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.tokenizer.explain(text)
```

**Output**

```
[('TOKEN', 'Schedule'),
 ('TOKEN', 'time'),
 ('TOKEN', 'with'),
 ('TOKEN', 'me'),
 ('TOKEN', 'Google'),
 ('INFIX', '<'),
 ('TOKEN', 'https://nam02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url'),
 ('INFIX', '='),
 ('TOKEN', 'http://calendly.com'),
 ('INFIX', '/'),
 ('TOKEN', 'helloKitty'),
 ('SUFFIX', '>')]
```

I understand that my incoming data is in a bad format but I except my data to be always in the format `alphaNumericCharacters<https`. One solution to fixing this would be adding a space before the `<` but as I do care about the exact index where the matches occur, it would affect the integrity of the data.

What would be the best way to extract the URL as a single URL without affecting the integrity of the data?

---

### Update:

The actual URL that I am trying to detect is a lot messier than I posted (the URLs have sensitive data embedded in them so was hesitant to post here, sorry about that; I have made more representative dummy URLs below).

The regex that matches the URLs that I want to match is `(?<=<)https?.*?(?=>)` . A working example can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/Fyaqpo/1/)

**Note**: I need the normal `token.like_url` to work as expected as this is just one edge case of url that I am trying to add to my detection process.

```
John Smith
CEO| Github
Website<https://asia04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://github.com/?utm_source=Email&utm_medium=Signature&data=04|01|John.Smith@github.com|e96d7cd187574884454708f8772e91g2|cd1e96k8h3da442a930b235cac54cd5c|0|0|756390346193879231|Unknown|WTFpbZGsb3d8eyQWIkoiDC4wLPjJmMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLDJZVCD6Mn0=|1010&sdata=JULP0n6z7CuNKTqTm1uNje6LV2VyPZ2h1C43m5gHWTs=&reserved=0> | Twitter<https://asia04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://twitter.com/Github&data=04|01|John.Smith@github.com|d07d7Cb187574996654709d8772e92f3|cd6a8a3da442a930b235cac24db5c|0|0|66789642193359231|Unknown|WTFpbZGsb3d8eyQWIkoiDC4wLPjJmMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLDJZVCD6Mn0=|1000&sdata=lZ+LJJkALu4aI1mq6xllSFGGscukF1tc2bLJi4Ys9LE=&reserved=0> | LinkedIn<https://asia04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://www.linkedin.com/company/github/&data=04|01|John.Smith@github.com|d06d7ab187574664454709d8662e81f3|cd1e96a8a3da442a904b235cac24db5c|0|0|657480399193999229|Unknown|WTFpbZGsb3d8eyQWIkoiDC4wLPjJmMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLDMBTiI6Ik1haWwiLDJZVCD6Mn0=|1000&sdata=F1CDkxQBSHCKyG9oosromvwaLqmaB/KrgyysnSGy/SM=&reserved=0>
```

```py
import spacy
from spacy.lang.tokenizer_exceptions import URL_PATTERN
text = "John Smith\nCEO| Github\nWebsite<https://asia04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://github.com/?utm_source=Email&utm_medium=Signature&data=04|01|John.Smith@github.com|e96d7cd187574884454708f8772e91g2|cd1e96k8h3da442a930b235cac54cd5c|0|0|756390346193879231|Unknown|WTFpbZGsb3d8eyQWIkoiDC4wLPjJmMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLDJZVCD6Mn0=|1010&sdata=JULP0n6z7CuNKTqTm1uNje6LV2VyPZ2h1C43m5gHWTs=&reserved=0> | Twitter<https://asia04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://twitter.com/Github&data=04|01|John.Smith@github.com|d07d7Cb187574996654709d8772e92f3|cd6a8a3da442a930b235cac24db5c|0|0|66789642193359231|Unknown|WTFpbZGsb3d8eyQWIkoiDC4wLPjJmMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLDJZVCD6Mn0=|1000&sdata=lZ+LJJkALu4aI1mq6xllSFGGscukF1tc2bLJi4Ys9LE=&reserved=0> | LinkedIn<https://asia04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://www.linkedin.com/company/github/&data=04|01|John.Smith@github.com|d06d7ab187574664454709d8662e81f3|cd1e96a8a3da442a904b235cac24db5c|0|0|657480399193999229|Unknown|WTFpbZGsb3d8eyQWIkoiDC4wLPjJmMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLDMBTiI6Ik1haWwiLDJZVCD6Mn0=|1000&sdata=F1CDkxQBSHCKyG9oosromvwaLqmaB/KrgyysnSGy/SM=&reserved=0>"
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
custom_infixes = [URL_PATTERN[1:-1]] + list(nlp.Defaults.infixes)
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(custom_infixes).finditer
for t in nlp.tokenizer.explain(nlp(text).text):
    print(t)
```

Output

```
('TOKEN', 'John')
('TOKEN', 'Smith')
('TOKEN', 'CEO|')
('TOKEN', 'Github')
('INFIX', 'Website<https://asia04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://github.com/?utm_source=Email&utm_medium=Signature&data=04|01|John.Smith@github.com')
('TOKEN', '|e96d7cd187574884454708f8772e91g2|cd1e96k8h3da442a930b235cac54cd5c|0|0|756390346193879231|Unknown|WTFpbZGsb3d8eyQWIkoiDC4wLPjJmMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLDJZVCD6Mn0=|1010&sdata')
('INFIX', '=')
('TOKEN', 'JULP0n6z7CuNKTqTm1uNje6LV2VyPZ2h1C43m5gHWTs=&reserved=0')
('SUFFIX', '>')
('TOKEN', '|')
('INFIX', 'Twitter<https://asia04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://twitter.com/Github&data=04|01|John.Smith@github.com')
('TOKEN', '|d07d7Cb187574996654709d8772e92f3|cd6a8a3da442a930b235cac24db5c|0|0|66789642193359231|Unknown|WTFpbZGsb3d8eyQWIkoiDC4wLPjJmMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLDJZVCD6Mn0=|1000&sdata')
('INFIX', '=')
('TOKEN', 'lZ+LJJkALu4aI1mq6xllSFGGscukF1tc2bLJi4Ys9LE=&reserved=0')
('SUFFIX', '>')
('TOKEN', '|')
('INFIX', 'LinkedIn<https://asia04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://www.linkedin.com/company/github/&data=04|01|John.Smith@github.com')
('TOKEN', '|d06d7ab187574664454709d8662e81f3|cd1e96a8a3da442a904b235cac24db5c|0|0|657480399193999229|Unknown|WTFpbZGsb3d8eyQWIkoiDC4wLPjJmMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLDMBTiI6Ik1haWwiLDJZVCD6Mn0=|1000&sdata')
('INFIX', '=')
('TOKEN', 'F1CDkxQBSHCKyG9oosromvwaLqmaB')
('INFIX', '/')
('TOKEN', 'KrgyysnSGy')
('INFIX', '/')
('TOKEN', 'SM=&reserved=0')
('SUFFIX', '>')
```

I tried adding my custom url regex for this case to the infixes like so but this didnt work.

```py
import spacy
from spacy.lang.tokenizer_exceptions import URL_PATTERN
text = "John Smith\nCEO| Github\nWebsite<https://asia04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://github.com/?utm_source=Email&utm_medium=Signature&data=04|01|John.Smith@github.com|e96d7cd187574884454708f8772e91g2|cd1e96k8h3da442a930b235cac54cd5c|0|0|756390346193879231|Unknown|WTFpbZGsb3d8eyQWIkoiDC4wLPjJmMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLDJZVCD6Mn0=|1010&sdata=JULP0n6z7CuNKTqTm1uNje6LV2VyPZ2h1C43m5gHWTs=&reserved=0> | Twitter<https://asia04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://twitter.com/Github&data=04|01|John.Smith@github.com|d07d7Cb187574996654709d8772e92f3|cd6a8a3da442a930b235cac24db5c|0|0|66789642193359231|Unknown|WTFpbZGsb3d8eyQWIkoiDC4wLPjJmMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLDJZVCD6Mn0=|1000&sdata=lZ+LJJkALu4aI1mq6xllSFGGscukF1tc2bLJi4Ys9LE=&reserved=0> | LinkedIn<https://asia04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://www.linkedin.com/company/github/&data=04|01|John.Smith@github.com|d06d7ab187574664454709d8662e81f3|cd1e96a8a3da442a904b235cac24db5c|0|0|657480399193999229|Unknown|WTFpbZGsb3d8eyQWIkoiDC4wLPjJmMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLDMBTiI6Ik1haWwiLDJZVCD6Mn0=|1000&sdata=F1CDkxQBSHCKyG9oosromvwaLqmaB/KrgyysnSGy/SM=&reserved=0>"
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
custom_infixes = [r'(?<=<)https?.*?(?=>)']  + list(nlp.Defaults.infixes)
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(custom_infixes).finditer
for t in nlp.tokenizer.explain(nlp(text).text):
    print(t)
```

Comment: It is a case where I'd rather use a regex, `m = re.search(r'(?<=<)http[^>]*', text)` and then you have both the text value in `m.group()` and the start (`m.start()`) and end (`m.end()`) positions.

Comment: What do you think? Or do you want to redefine the tokenizer to match URLs?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks a lot for answering this. I cross asked this question on Github. You can find the link [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/6999). That is the direction which would make sense for me to head given my problem definition but I still have not been able to make much headway. Detecting the URL as an `infix` or using `url_match` would be ideal.  I have updated the question to give more context.

Comment: The reason I am hesitant to redefine the tokenizer is because this is one edge case that I am handling, and the tokenizer works fairly well for rest of the problem in hand. When would be it appropriate to redefine the tokenizer?

Answer (score 0):

```
import spacy
nlp= spacy.blank("en")
doc=nlp(text)
url_list=[token.text for token in doc if token.like_url]
print(url_list)
#try it
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**